# Trying to search a table for strings using a form?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where a user can put in string to search a database

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search the Database</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form action="search.php" method="post">
     Search: <input type="text" name="search" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    </body>
</html
```

From here I search the db with a query

search.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "db","pw")  or die (mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db ("stories"); //This selects the specific database you want your results to come from (as you may have more than one database). Change "test" to your database name.

$search = $_POST['search']; //This grabs everything your user has put into the search field (which has been labelled as "search" earlier from the .HTML page).

$sql = mysql_query("select * from stories where stories like '%$term%'");  //Assigns a variable called "$sql" to the result of your "search". And the use of LIKE allows you to only have to type in (for example if you were searching a name).. Jord instead of the full Jordan.

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  //We start a "while" loop so you can output multiple results. Also we assign an array "$row" to each database table column you would like to display. Below is an example if you wanted multiple tables to be searched through and displayed if a match is found.


    echo '<br/> Result '.$row['stories'];

    }

?>
```

I don't get any errors, but I don't get any output either. Is something wrong with the query?

Comment: `$term` should be `$search` in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing the search string in variable `$search` and searching for it with an undefined variable `$term`. Try with this.

```
$search = $_POST['search']; 
$sql = mysql_query("select * from stories where stories like '%$search%'");
```